# SharePoint online REST API: Post payload to create new item with Multi-Choice field

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, odata, sharepoint-online, office365api

I am using Python sharePoint online library -[Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client) to create new list item. I am able to successfully create new list.

When I try to create new list with Multi-choice field (think it's a custom field), I receive an error.

**Payload:**

```
{'__metadata': {'type': 'SP.Data.MyListItem'}, 'Title': 'Task Created by Python Script',
                           'CategoryDescription': 'This is a test Task created by Python script  with the help of Office 365 library.',                               
                           'Multichoicefield':{
                               '__metadata' : {'type' : 'Collection(Edm.String)' },
                               'results': ['value1', 'value2']
                               }
                           }
```

On running with above payload, receive `An open collection property 'Multichoicefield' was found. In OData, open collection properties are not supported.", "400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:`

Seems like OData stopped supporting this. Does anyone know how to create with multi-choice field

Answer (score 0):

Open collection properties are supported in more recent versions of OData and the OData libraries.  It appears that your ClientContext is using an outdated version of the ODataLibrary.

Answer (score -1):

Check the "Multichoicefield" field settings as the screenshots below.

[image]

And try to use the REST API with JavaScript in script editor web part in SharePoint page to check if it works.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var listName="CustomList";
function AddListItem(){
    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var item = {
        '__metadata': {'type': itemType },
        'Title': 'test',
        'Multichoicefield':{
           '__metadata' : {'type' : 'Collection(Edm.String)' },
           'results': ['value1', 'value2']
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("succeeded.");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}  
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="AddListItem()" value="Add"/>
```

If the JavaScript with REST API works in your environment, you need check the code in python.

Comment: I checked the field settings, it's same as you mentioned here. I tried to run the script on script editor as you instructed, but [Script Editor](https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000265208-how-to-add-javascript-code-to-a-page-using-the-script-editor-web-part) is not available under Media and Content. Tried to [enable script](https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000188451-prerequisite-1-enabling-scripting-capabilities), but it seems like it will take 24hrs.

Comment: Since field settings are same, do you think there is any problem to create list with the Payload shared in the question? Also, seems like enabling script editor can be done by SharePoint Admin which I am not

Comment: The error is clear that `An open collection property 'Multichoicefield' was found. In OData, open collection properties are not supported.`. But, not sure if it's not supported what is the supported type then